# Javascript: How to preserve namespace when using XMLSerialier.serializeToString()?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, serialization

I have an SVG element inside HTML document that I'd like to export as text.

I know HTML doesn't have namespace hence it doesn't honor one, that is probably why I lose namespace prefixes on my SVG element.

Are there ways to preserve it other than writing my own serializer?

Example code:

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var svg = document.getElementById('mySvg');
console.log(s.serializeToString(svg)); //All namespace prefixes are gone!
```

Edit: apparently this is Chrome's (tested on v17) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is chrome's bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88295

For now I have to manually do a search/replace namespaces after calls to `serializeToString`.